Your own rpc node or a paid private node?
Is there any sense to build your own powerful server to become a rpc node and get information for defi from websockets faster than from paid nodes? Or is it better to use private paid nodes? How to understand which paid nodes are the fastest for defi? Which ones can you recommend?

these are good and relevant questions that are not specific to Solana but all Infrastructure.
Some questions to consider
Do you have the time to manage the server
Do you have the skills?
Are you better out sourcing vs in sourcing? It's an opportunity cost
The most important question I ask myself is am I am infra provider or am I app developer?
Another angle is to consider spending time and money (as a research expense) to see how the other providers to it.
You can find all the RPC on Solana here
Solana RPC Providers

Running your own powerful RPC (Remote Procedure Call) node can be faster and more reliable for DeFi (Decentralized Finance) than using paid nodes since you have full control over it. However, it can be costly and requires technical skills to maintain.
If you prefer convenience and professional support, paid private nodes are a good option. They manage all the technical aspects for you.
To find the fastest paid nodes for DeFi, look for benchmarks and user reviews.
Popular providers include:
1. Triton
2. Helius
3. Infura
4. Alchemy
5. QuickNode
These services are known for speed and reliability.
